# Software Rendering: Why aren't my vertices being transformed?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a basic software rendering project and am running into an issue. I've been refactoring and cleaning for a bit so a few things has changed in the rendering code. The issue I'm having at the moment is that even though my list of vertices is being transformed, when the model is rendered, it hasn't been transformed at all. I'm wondering why this is happening since I'm passing objects (Vec3) to the transform functions, and they are being manipulated within those functions, why aren't those changes remaining?

```
package PixelVision.Rendering;

import PixelVision.Math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * This class sits in an implementation of the Engine. This Object does
 * everything from abstracting the rendering of meshes, to scaling the
 * rendered coordinates to the screen size.
 * 
 * Full List:
 * ~Scales Coordinates to ScreenSpace. (0, 0) is the center of the screen.
 * ~Performs triangle clipping of triangles that go outside the screen.
 * ~abstracts the rendering of meshes
 */

public final class SWRenderer {

    private Bitmap target;
    public ArrayList<Model> Models;
    Mat4x4 projectionMat, viewMat;
    Vec3 Camera, CameraDir, LightDir;

    public SWRenderer() {
        Models = new ArrayList<Model>();
    }

    public void SetRenderTarget(Bitmap tar) {
        target = tar;
    }

    public void Init() {
        projectionMat = Mat4x4.GetProjection(90f, 1f, 100f);
        Camera = new Vec3();
        LightDir = new Vec3(0, 0, -1f);
    }

    public void Render() {
        for(Model m : Models) {
            RenderModel(m);
        }
    }

    private void RenderModel(Model model) {

        Vec3[] vertices = model.getMesh().GetVertexData().clone();
        Triangle[] tris = model.getMesh().GetTriangles().clone();

        for(int v = 0; v < vertices.length; v++) {
            WorldTransform(vertices[v], model);
            ViewTransform(vertices[v]);
            ProjectionTransform(vertices[v]);
        }

        for(Triangle tri : tris) {
            Vec2 v1, v2, v3;
            v1 = new Vec2(vertices[tri.Verts[0]].x, vertices[tri.Verts[0]].y);
            v2 = new Vec2(vertices[tri.Verts[1]].x, vertices[tri.Verts[1]].y);
            v3 = new Vec2(vertices[tri.Verts[2]].x, vertices[tri.Verts[2]].y);

            ScaleVertexToScreen(v1);
            ScaleVertexToScreen(v2);
            ScaleVertexToScreen(v3);

            RasterizeTriangle(v1, v2, v3);
        }
    }

    private void WorldTransform(Vec3 vert, Model currentModel) {

        vert = Mat4x4.Mul(Mat4x4.GetScale(currentModel.getScale()), vert); //Scaling

        vert = Mat4x4.Mul(Mat4x4.GetTranslation(currentModel.getOrigin().GetNegative()), vert); //Rotation about models origin
        vert = Mat4x4.Mul(Mat4x4.GetRotation(currentModel.getRotation()), vert);
        vert = Mat4x4.Mul(Mat4x4.GetTranslation(currentModel.getOrigin()), vert);

        vert = Mat4x4.Mul(Mat4x4.GetTranslation(currentModel.getLocation()), vert); //Translation
    }

    private void ViewTransform(Vec3 vert) {
        //not yet implemented
    }

    private void ProjectionTransform(Vec3 vert) {
        Mat4x4.Mul(projectionMat, vert);
    }

    private void ScaleVertexToScreen(Vec2 vert) {

        vert.x += 1.0f;
        vert.y += 1.0f;
        vert.x *= 0.5f * (float)target.GetWidth();
        vert.y *= 0.5f * (float)target.GetHeight();
    }

    private void RasterizeTriangle(Vec2 v1, Vec2 v2, Vec2 v3) {
        Color c = new Color(Color.RED);
        Draw.DrawLine(v1, v2, target, c);
        Draw.DrawLine(v2, v3, target, c);
        Draw.DrawLine(v3, v1, target, c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignments for `vert` in the `WorldTransform` function only affect the reference for the local `vert` variable. This does not alter the referenced object and hence does not transform your vertices. Your transform functions(if assignment is necessary), should return the new value.

```java
vertices[v]=WorldTransform(vertices[v], model);
...
private Vec3 WorldTransform(Vec3 vert, Model currentModel){
    //Apply transformations
    return vert;
}
```